# How to remove duplicate values from a aggregate list when using LISTAGG() in oracle SQL?

Tags: sql, oracle, listagg

I have created a table:

```
Grade FName LName-

A     JOHN     M

A     JOE      M

A     JOAKIM   M
```

Used Listagg() to get a concatenated aggregation of Fname & Lname using the query:

```
SELECT GRADE,listagg(st_name || ';' || st_last_name, ';')
        within group ( order by st_name) as names FROM STUDENTS GROUP BY GRADE;
```

The output that I get is:

```
GRADE    Name

A     JOAKIM;M;JOE;M;JOHN;M

B        BROAD;M

C        KEVIN;M;SEEHO;M
```

I want to keep the only one 'M' in the name column and want to discard the other M's. Please provide me with any suggestions on how to accomplish this.Please do not be specific to this question. Thanks!

Example:
KEVIN;M;SEEHO;M should be  KEVIN;M;SEEHO, JOAKIM;M;JOE;M;JOHN;M should be JOAKIM;M;JOE;JOHN and so on...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a simple query, you can use a subquery:

```
SELECT GRADE, listagg(name, ';') within group (order by name) as names
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT GRADE, st_name || ';' || st_last_name as name
      FROM STUDENTS
     ) s
GROUP BY GRADE;
```

I find it odd that you are using a semi-colon both to separate `st_name` and `st_last_name` and to separate the different values.  I would expect different separators to be used -- `'john;smith;jane;doe;'` is harder to read than `'john,smith;jane,doe'`.

Comment: I have a requirement which needs M to be once and that list is being set in a DTO object. Can we do this without the subquery?

Comment: How about editing the question (there's an [edit] button just below the question tags) and include some test data? Thanks.

Comment: I have added the data. Can you please help now?